# Link to supplementary table links to main text table in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have been using the following LaTeX command to create supplementary tables in my R Markdown documents:

```
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{\setcounter{table}{0}  \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}} \setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}}
```

However, recently the linkage has broken. For example, when clicking on "Table S1" in-text, I will be taken to Table 1. Please see the example below:

````
---
title: 'Test Rmd document'
output:
  pdf_document
header-includes: 
- \newcommand{\beginsupplement}{\setcounter{table}{0}  \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}} \setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}}
---

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
```

## Main body
This is a main text table (\autoref{main_table}). There is also a supplementary table (\autoref{supplementary_table}).

```{r}
table <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)
kable(table, 
      caption = "Main body table \\label{main_table}",
        format = "markdown")
```

\newpage
# Supplementary materials
\beginsupplement

```{r}
table <- tibble(a = 7:9, b = 10:12)
kable(table, 
      caption = "Supplementary table \\label{supplementary_table}",
        format = "markdown")
```
````

Rendering the above gives [this](https://drive.proton.me/urls/24YTVYM7P0#nhvERKJkHR5N) pdf document. Why is "(Table S1)" linking to Table 1?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add `\renewcommand`s for both `\thetable` and `\theHtable`:

```
header-includes: 
- \newcommand{\beginsupplement}{\setcounter{table}{0}  \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}} \renewcommand{\theHtable}{S\arabic{table}} \setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}} \renewcommand{\theHfigure}{S\arabic{figure}}}
```

Same goes for `\thefigure`/`\theHfigure`.

(see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304816))